# Yield slower than return in some cases?

Tags: python, function, return, yield

I'm trying to learn use cases for yield vs return. Here, I'm cleaning up a dictionary. But it appears return is faster here. Is it the case that yield is mostly faster only when we don't need to run through all iterations 0 to imax?

[image]

Comment: Why are you assuming that the generator should be faster? The generator has more overhead.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images of text.

Comment: `yield` and `return` have different use cases - it's not just that one is faster or slower than the other, it's that they do different things. Inside a function, the `return` statement is always the last thing that is executed, and effectively halts the function and returns control flow to the caller. Inside a generator, `yield` only interrupts the flow, which can be resumed on the next call to `next( )` on that generator.

Comment: You're also having a bug in the `new_dict[modified_key]==False` line, I think you meant to use `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: You also have a bug because you're referring to a variable called `new_dic` and another called `new_dict`; I assume it's a typo and they're supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: Generators optimize for *memory* use (by generating values on demand rather than all at once), not for speed.

Comment: Also note that if `val` is guaranteed to be either True or False, then `if val == False: new_dic[modified_key] = True elif val == True: new_dic[modified_key] = False` can be shortened to `if not val: new_dic[modified_key] = True else new_dic[modified_key] = False` or even better `new_dic[modified_key] = False if val else True` or even much much much better `new_dic[modified_key] = not val`

Comment: Are there keys where `'enabl' in key` and `'disabl' in key` are both True? What should be the behaviour in that case? Consider replacing the second `if` with an `elif`.

Comment: Are there keys that contain neither `'enabl'` nor `'disabl'`? If there are, they are not going to survive to `new_dic`. Consider adding an `else`.

Comment: @Stef Thank you for your time. I understand now mb used is probably the right metric to compare. (not always a linear relation w time to execute, i suppose). Yes, only enabl or disabl and always True or False.  new_dic[modified_key] = not val is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShivamAnand Note that the two running times, 7.3 microseconds and 10.8 microseconds, are actually quite close. It's entirely possible the difference is due to something else than just "yield versus return"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR:**

> The differences in timings you see is due to the difference in
> performance of building a dictionary item by item vs building a list
> of tuples then casting that to a dictionary. NOT as a result of some
> performance difference with return vs yield.

**Details:**

As you have implemented and observed with your two strategies, the one that `returns` is faster than the one that `yeilds` but that might also be as a result of the differences in your strategies rather than in `return` vs `yeild`.

Your `return` code builds a dictionary piece by piece and then returns it while your `yield` strategy returns tuples that you gather into a list and cast that to a dictionary.

What happens if we compare the timings of returning a list of tuples vs yeilding tuples into a list? What we will find is that the performance is essentially the same.

First let's determine 3 methods that will ultimately produce the same results (your dictionary)

First, let's build some data to test with:

```
import random

## --------------------------
## Some random input data
## --------------------------
feature_dict = {
    f"{'enable' if i%2 else 'disable'}_{i}": random.choice([True, False])
    for i in range(1000)
}
## --------------------------
```

Next, our three test methods.

```
## --------------------------
## Your "return" strategy
## --------------------------
def reverse_disable_to_enable_return(dic):
    new_dic = {}
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if "enabl" in key:
            new_dic[key] = val
        if "disabl" in key:
            modified_key = key.replace("disable", "enable")
            if val == False:
                new_dic[modified_key] = True
            elif val == True:
                new_dic[modified_key] = False
    return new_dic
## --------------------------

## --------------------------
## Your "yield" strategy (requires cast to dict for compatibility with return)
## --------------------------
def reverse_disable_to_enable_yield(dic):
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if "enabl" in key:
            yield key, val
        if "disabl" in key:
            modified_key = key.replace("disable", "enable")
            if val == False:
                yield modified_key, True
            elif val == True:
                yield modified_key, False
## --------------------------

## --------------------------
## Your "return" strategy modified to return a list to match the yield
## --------------------------
def reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples(dic):
    new_list = []
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if "enabl" in key:
            new_list.append((key, val))
        if "disabl" in key:
            modified_key = key.replace("disable", "enable")
            if val == False:
                new_list.append((modified_key, True))
            elif val == True:
                new_list.append((modified_key, False))
    return new_list
## --------------------------
```

Now, lets validate that these are essentially the same from a result perspective:

```
## --------------------------
## Do these produce the same result?
## --------------------------
a = reverse_disable_to_enable_return(feature_dict)
b = dict(reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples(feature_dict))
c = dict(reverse_disable_to_enable_yield(feature_dict))

print(a == feature_dict)
print(a == b)
print(a == c)
## --------------------------
```

As we hoped, this tells us:

```
False
True
True
```

Now, what about timing?

Let's establish the base setup context:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import random
feature_dict = {
    f"{'enable' if i%2 else 'disable'}_{i}": random.choice([True, False])
    for i in range(1000)
}

def reverse_disable_to_enable_return(dic):
    new_dic = {}
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if "enabl" in key:
            new_dic[key] = val
        if "disabl" in key:
            modified_key = key.replace("disable", "enable")
            if val == False:
                new_dic[modified_key] = True
            elif val == True:
                new_dic[modified_key] = False
    return new_dic

def reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples(dic):
    new_list = []
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if "enabl" in key:
            new_list.append((key, val))
        if "disabl" in key:
            modified_key = key.replace("disable", "enable")
            if val == False:
                new_list.append((modified_key, True))
            elif val == True:
                new_list.append((modified_key, False))
    return new_list

def reverse_disable_to_enable_yield(dic):
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if "enabl" in key:
            yield key, val
        if "disabl" in key:
            modified_key = key.replace("disable", "enable")
            if val == False:
                yield modified_key, True
            elif val == True:
                yield modified_key, False
'''
```

now we are ready to do some timing....

Let's try:

```
timings_a = timeit.timeit("reverse_disable_to_enable_return(feature_dict)", setup=setup, number=10_000)
print(f"reverse_disable_to_enable_return: {timings_a}")

timings_b = timeit.timeit("dict(reverse_disable_to_enable_yield(feature_dict))", setup=setup, number=10_000)
print(f"reverse_disable_to_enable_yield: {timings_b}")
```

On my laptop this gives:

```
reverse_disable_to_enable_return: 2.30
reverse_disable_to_enable_yield: 2.71
```

Confirming what you observe that `yield` is apparently slower than `return`..

**BUT, remember, this is not really an apples to apple test.**

Let's try our 3rd method

```
timings_c = timeit.timeit("dict(reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples(feature_dict))", setup=setup, number=10_000)
print(f"reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples: {timings_c}")
```

giving us a much closer match to our yield case:

```
reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples: 2.9009995
```

In fact, lets take the cast to `dict()` out and look at returning a list of tuples vs yeilding tuples to build a list...

```
timings_b = timeit.timeit("list(reverse_disable_to_enable_yield(feature_dict))", setup=setup, number=10_000)
print(f"reverse_disable_to_enable_yield: {timings_b}")

timings_c = timeit.timeit("reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples(feature_dict)", setup=setup, number=10_000)
print(f"reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples: {timings_c}")
```

Now we get:

```
reverse_disable_to_enable_yield: 2.13
reverse_disable_to_enable_return_apples: 2.13
```

Showing us that over 10k calls the time to build and return a list of tuples is essentially identical to the time to yield those same tuples and build a list. As we might expect.

**Summary:**

The differences in timings you see is due to the difference in performance of building a dictionary item by item vs building a list of tuples then casting that to a dictionary. NOT as a result of some performance difference with return vs yield.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what more you need, as the comments already explained it perfectly, but here goes:

A simple example of a generator could be `custom_range()`, that will produce numbers from `0` to `top` by the increments of 1. When you use it, it doesn't produce all the numbers at once, so you don't need to store them all immediatelly. It only `yield`s you one number at a time. The main use here is - no need to store the 100 000 variables at the same time.

```
def custom_range(top):

    x = 0

    while x < top:
        yield x
        x += 1


for i in custom_range(100000):
    ...
```

But if you were to `return` the `list` of variables, it would require them all stored.

```
def custom_return(top):

    out = []
    x = 0

    while x < top:
        out.append(x)
        x += 1

    return out

my_list = custom_return(100000)

for i in my_list:
    ...
```

So I don't think a direct comparison is fair for these two things, as they both have their own usecase.